# MediaPipeline doesn't download file

Tags: python, scrapy

I can't figure out why my pipeline doesn't save files. Here's the code:

```
VIDEOS_DIR = '/home/dmitry/videos'

class VideoDownloadPipeline(MediaPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        return Request(item['file'], meta={'item': item})

    def media_downloaded(self, response, request, info):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        video = response.body
        video_basename = item['file'].split('/')[-1]
        new_filename = os.path.join(VIDEOS_DIR, video_basename)
        f = open(new_filename, 'wb')
        f.write(video)
        f.close()

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        item['file'] = item['file'].split('/')[-1]
        return item
```

I had some other code before that but it wasn't concurrent so I had to wait for every video to download first before continuing parsing:

```
class VideoDownloadPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        video_basename = item['file'].split('/')[-1]
        new_filename = os.path.join(VIDEOS_DIR, video_basename)
        downloaded = False
        for i in range(5):
            try:
                video = urllib2.urlopen(item['file']).read()
                downloaded = True
                break
            except:
                continue
        if not downloaded:
            raise DropItem("Couldn't download file from %s" % item)
        f = open(new_filename, 'wb')
        f.write(video)
        f.close()
        item['file'] = video_basename
        return item
```

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

BOT_NAME = 'videos_parser'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['videos_parser.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'videos_parser.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'videos_parser.pipelines.VideoFileSizePipeline': 300,
    'videos_parser.pipelines.VideoExistingInDBPipeline': 350,
    'videos_parser.pipelines.VideoModeratePipeline': 400,
    'videos_parser.pipelines.VideoDownloadPipeline': 500,
    'videos_parser.pipelines.JsonWriterPipeline': 800,
}

EXTENSIONS = {
    'scrapy.contrib.closespider.CloseSpider': 100,
}

CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT = 50

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 60
```

**UPDATE**

I added some `log.msg()` statements as in `get_media_requests` and `media_downloaded` and as I can see `get_media_requests` was invoked and `media_download` was not because of the:

```
2014-07-23 08:58:20+0400 [xhamster] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://somesite/video.mp4> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost'>>]
```

But I'm able to download this file using browser.

Comment: You may want to add some `log.debug()` statements in the different methods to understand where the processing is blocked or skipped (and share the logs with us). Another option is to use [`FilesPipeline`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/files.py) which is similar to `ImagesPipeline`

Comment: `[xhamster]` eh? I wonder what kind of videos you're scraping ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply missed the line with information that said file was dropped by spider because of the `DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT`.